# how to get compare object type and value together

Tags: java, equals

I am posting a chunk of problematic code here. I am trying to compare two object types and their values simultaneously.

```
    public boolean equals(Object val1)
{

    if (!(val1 instanceof ParentClass))

    return false;

    ParentClass val2 = (ParentClass) val1;

    if ((val1.getClass().equals(val2.getClass())) && val1.getVal().equals(val2.getVal()));
    System.out.println("Both objects belong to same class  and the values are equal too!!");

    return true;

}
```

I have this chunk in my parent class and i am getting errors(The method getVal() is undefined for the type Object) in the above IF condition. Could you please suggest me a solution so that i could compare the object type and values in one go.
actually ParentClass is my parent and i have several derived classes and i am using the Object's equals method to compare the type of base and derived objects.
Also How can i verify my equals using Object's hashCode?
Please let me know your suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your comparison:

```
if ((val1.getClass().equals(val2.getClass())) && val1.getVal().equals(val2.getVal()));
```

That's comparing `val1` and `val2` - but those are the same reference, given the previous line! You want to be comparing `this` with `val2`. For example:

```
if (this.getClass().equals(val2.getClass()) && this.getVal().equals(val2.getVal()))
```

(The explicit `this.` part is unnecessary here, but I've included it for the sake of clarity.)

Also note that due to the way `Class<>` objects are constructed/cached, you can just check for reference equality:

```
if (this.getClass() == val2.getClass() && this.getVal().equals(val2.getVal()))
```

Comment: i have already tried this way too but i am getting an error as "Cannot invoke equals(double) on the primitive type double"

Comment: @user2759565 If your `getVal()` returns double, use `==` to compare them. Or as usually with floating point, compare within a delta (depends on how exact you intend your equals() to be).

Comment: But when i am using equals for two objects one of parent and other of its child with equal values, it returns false.Please correct me.

Comment: @user2759565: Yes, you've explicitly said that it should, using `this.getClass().equals(val2.getClass())`. If that's not what you intended, why do you have that condition? (It's a common condition in equality comparisons.)